# Delphi TFDConnection Exception occured project build in release mode

Tags: delphi, pascal, firedac

In run this Code in Delphi. It works fine if I run this in "Debug mode", but when I am build this project in Release Mod I got a Access Violation Exception. I really dont know why...

Code:

```
if not SQLConnection.Connected then begin
  DatabaseValues := TStringList.Create;
  try
    IniFile := TPataxPlusGlobal.ClientIniFilename;
    if FileExists(IniFile) then begin
      TIniFileHelper.ReadSectionValuesFromIniFile(INI_SECTION_DATABASE, DatabaseValues, IniFile);
      SQLConnection.TxOptions.AutoCommit := cbAutoCommit.Checked;
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('Server=' + DatabaseValues.Values['Server']);
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('Database=' + 'pps');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('User_Name=' + DatabaseValues.Values['Nutzer']);
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('Password=' + TPataxPlusUtil.DecryptStr(DatabaseValues.Values['Passwort']));
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('Port=' + DatabaseValues.Values['Port']);

      SQLConnection.Open;  //This line throw the Exception
    end;
  finally
    DatabaseValues.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And this is the Exception:

> Access Violation at address 00000000 in module 'PataxPlusClient.exe' read of address 00000000

Comment: Install MadExcept.  Something is `nil`, we can't know what it is without knowing what line the exception happened on or without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: You need to verify that SQLConnection.Params contains what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

what component used for connection?

also check line

```
SQLConnection.Params.Add('Password=' + TPataxPlusUtil.DecryptStr(DatabaseValues.Values['Passwort']));
```

has the connection component been created?

Comment: This may be better off in a comment since you are asking for more information. If the information leads to a solution, then create an answer with a solution to the question.